# Why does the sum of a partition of 1 not equal 1?

Tags: spacing

In this MWE, I have five elements on a line: three figures with 32% each, and two spaces with 2% each. 3*32+2*2=100. So I expect these items to fit on one line:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}%
    $32+2+32+2+32=100$, right?
    \begin{figure}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
        \hspace{0.02\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
        \hspace{0.02\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
    \end{figure}%
\end{document}%
```

Why don't they?

[image]

Bonus question: What influence does the `geometry` package have?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're losing sight of the fact that sums of real (double-entendre intended) calculations with non-integers may introduce rounding error issues.

With TeX, all internal length calculations are done in terms of multiples of `sp` units, where `1pt=65536sp`. Depending on the exact value of `\linewidth`, `3(0.32\linewidth)+2(0.02\linewidth)` may work out to be either slightly more or slightly less than `1\linewidth`. In one case, i.e., with the document class-defined default value of `\linewidth`, the rounded sum is slightly more than `1\linewidth`; hence, the third graph gets kicked to the next line. If `geometry` is loaded, the default value of `\linewidth` is larger. It also so happens that with the modified default, the rounded sum is slightly less than `1\linewidth` -- and all three graphs happily fit on one line.

At any rate, the issue wouldn't arise with proper coding technique: Use `\hfill` instead of `\hspace{0.02\linewidth}` to separate the graphs.

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I would like to upvote twice: once for the explanation, and once for the workaround with `\hfill`!

Comment: you need just \hfill (hence the `%`) as there is not room for two word spaces)

Comment: For anyone interested: One simple example to try, e.g., in MATLAB, is `0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3`, which equals `5.5511e-17` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error)

Comment: Another comment for those who would like to use different spacings, such as `\hspace{0.02\linewidth}` and `\hspace{0.035\linewidth}`: use `\hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill` and `\hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill`.

Comment: @bers: … or rather, `\hspace{\stretch{.2}}` and `\hspace{\stretch{.35}}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks! FWIW, I did test the example code *without* the `%` line terminators prior to posting the answer, to make sure that all 3 graph would indeed show up in one row, using the default text width (`345pt`) of the `article` document class with `10pt` as the main font size. Of course, if `\textwidth` were set to a smaller value, it would definitely become necessary to use the `%`device to prevent LaTeX from inserting extra spaces. Since we can't know how the example code might get used by future readers, it's definitely a good idea to feature the `%` symbols.